# Two SQL Statements to count a column form another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table just to store information about a project, such as the name of the project and the owners etc.

I have another table with many tasks that are associated with one project.

How can I run a query to show me all of the open tasks from the task table?

Here is my desired result set:

```
Project Name    Project Owner    Open Tasks
Test 1          Test Owner       5
Test 2          Test Owner       0
```

My sql statement:

```
SELECT [Project Name] as Name1, [Project Owner]
FROM ProjectNames
UNION
SELECT distinct(count) 
FROM ActionItems
WHERE ProjectName = Name1
Order By Name1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    pn.`Project Name`,
    pn.`project owner`,
    COUNT(ai.actions) AS `Open Tasks`
FROM ProjectNames AS pn
INNER JOIN ActionItems AS ai
    ON ai.`ProjectName` = pn.`Project Name`
GROUP BY pn.`Project Name`
ORDER BY `Open Tasks`
```

I think that'd work as desired. Change the column/table names accordingly.

Comment: So the query works amazingly when a project has a task. How can I also display the projects with 0 tasks?

Comment: If i understand correctly what you want just use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Comment: I tried that and it didn't change the results. Here is my query: `SELECT pn.[Project Name], pn.[Project Owner], COUNT(ai.ID) AS 'Open Tasks'
FROM ProjectNames AS pn
Left JOIN ActionItems AS ai
    ON ai.[Project Name] = pn.[Project Name]
where ai.Status <> 'Canceled'
and ai.Status <> 'Completed'
GROUP BY pn.[Project Name], [Project Owner]
ORDER BY 'Open Tasks''

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little tired I think the problem is in WHERE clause she also exclude and results where you don't have any task's can you try something like this and tell me if it's work: WHERE (ai.Status <> 'Canceled' and ai.Status <> 'Completed') OR `Open Tasks` IS NULL ... everything else should remain the same...

Comment: What @AleksandarMiladinovic suggested above. Use `where in` though -> `WHERE ai.Status NOT IN ('Cancelled', Completed') OR ...`

Comment: Yea @hjpotter92 is right NOT IN is much better solution for the first part of where clause... :) didn't think about that i try to figure out why Left Join wasn't include results when he should. In my head it was supposed to happen by default...